# How to change some value only the first time when one observable from switchMap changes

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I’m pretty new to rxjs and I guess I need some architectural advice. I’m trying to create some simple search app based on Google Books API and I’m stuck while it comes to pagination.

I have two observables queryParamValue$ and startIndex$ (both from user input, query from searchbar and start index increases while user clicks LoadMore button); this is the way how GoogleBooks advices to handle pagination (https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using#pagination).

I get a response, and I want to store the value of response.totalItems* as a “maximum” point for my pagination and change it only when queryParamValue changes. So, first request with given query “gives” me the totalItems value, list of first 20 books appropriate to query; next one gives me only list of next 20 books appropriate to query; when I change the queryParamValue (user changes input value) first request changes also the total value.

**Why I don't want to set the total every time** - This API doesn't show the value of all records, totalItems is - as I found out - an estimate of the number of items remaining from the current search index, not the total number of items. So the value changes after each request, which may confuse user if it comes to pagination. I thought that I can take the very first value and set it as a limit, it will be enough results for my needs, and more accurate than hardcoding an arbitray value.

So far I hardcoded the “total” value and I’m wondering if there is any rxjs idea to do what I want? My code so far:

```
  private apiUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?key=";
  private apiKey = environment.apikey;
  url = `${this.apiUrl}${this.apiKey}`;

  queryParamSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>("");
  queryParamValue$ = this.queryParamSubject.asObservable();

  private noResultsSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  noResultsMessage$ = this.noResultsSubject.asObservable();

  startIndex = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
  startIndex$ = this.startIndex.asObservable();

//should be an observable but for now hardcoded value
  total = 40;

areThereMoreBooksSubj = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
areThereMoreBooks$ = this.areThereMoreBooksSubj.asObservable();

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  books$ = combineLatest([
    this.queryParamValue$,
    this.startIndex$
  ]).pipe(
      switchMap(([query, index]) => query ? 
        this.http.get<Book[]>(`${this.url}&q=${query}&startIndex=${index}&maxResults=20`).pipe(
          map((response: any) => {
            if (response.items){
        //want to do this only once with given query so certainly not this way
              //this.total = response.totalItems;
              this.areThereMoreBooksSubj.next(this.total - this.startIndex.value > 0);
                return response.items.map((item: any) => {
                  return <Book> {
                    title: item.volumeInfo.title,
                    authors: item.volumeInfo.authors,
                    volumeLink: item.volumeInfo.infoLink,
                    coverImage: item.volumeInfo.imageLinks && item.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail
                    ? item.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail
                    : "https://via.placeholder.com/100x150"
                  }
                })
                } else{
                  this.noResultsSubject.next(true);
                  return [];
                }
              })
        //if query is empty (beginning of app) return observable of empty arr
        ) : of([])
      )
  )

  queryChanged(query: string): void{
    this.queryParamSubject.next(query)
    this.startIndex.next(0);
  }

  loadMoreBooks(): void{
    this.startIndex.next( this.startIndex.value + 20);
    this.areThereMoreBooksSubj.next(this.total - this.startIndex.value > 0 );
  }
```

Comment: Why can't you set the `total` every time? if `query` doesn't change, the `total` should be the same value. What's the problem with overriding `total` with the same value? Is it that you do not want the `total` subject to emit the same values multiple times?

Comment: @Helios thanks for the comment, I've edited my question to explain it

Comment: You could just do `if (query != lastQuery) {this.total = response.totalItems}` or if you want `total` to be a `Subject` it would be `if (query != lastQuery) {this.total.emit(response.totalItems)}` and set the `lastQuery` before you return from the `map` operator. But I guess it's not the rxjs way you wanted.